# Disable double tap (but keep one tap to click enabled) on touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I normally used the intuitive touchpad options on my MacBook Air under macOS (i.e. tap to click, three finger swipe to change desktops, three finger swipe up to show the window manager...) and want to disable what Ubuntu registers as dragging when I select text by double tapping it and moving the cursor.

How do I do that? I couldn't find any similar questions and don't even know how to search for the answer.

Yes that also means double tapping desktop icons to open them. I guess I'll just double click them without tapping.

Comment: Please, state your hardware in the body.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using X and libinput, I think that you're looking for the TappingDrag option which is described at https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/tapping.html#tap-and-drag and shown in `man libinput`:

```
       Option "TappingDrag" "bool"
              Enables or disables drag during tapping behavior ("tap-and-drag"). When enabled, a tap followed by a finger held down causes a single button down only, all  motions  of  that  finger  thus
              translate into dragging motion.  Tap-and-drag requires option Tapping to be enabled.
```

You might be able to configure it by running:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag false`

per [How to disable the "tap dragging"-feature in Ubuntu 18.04 (libinput) without disabling "tap to click"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032459/how-to-disable-the-tap-dragging-feature-in-ubuntu-18-04-libinput-without-dis?rq=1)

Comment: Man, this is awesome, thank you very much! Double Tap stills working and this useless feature to tap-drag doesn't, perfect! Only a small change to improve your answer, please fix to: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag false`

Answer (score 1):

Please, state your hardware in the body.

Code in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf` from [[SOLVED] Synaptics double-tap problem - Linux](https://www.pismotek.com/brainout/content/synaptics_linux_fix.php) for another attempt to get double-tap to work in your hardware

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "0"
        Option "TapButton3" "0"
    Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "MaxDoubleTapTime" "100"
EndSection
```

Not considering wipe with three finger here.

Stability: still much to improve for OS X level

Differential solution: KDE which has builtin configs there so maybe little better support, discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107532/how-to-enable-touchpad-scrolling-and-tapping-in-debian-wheezy-kde/107546#107546) for KDE

OS: Ubuntu or Debian 8.x/9.x
Window manager: Gnome 3.14 or one earlier